# Javascript Localstorage: Comparing input value with value stored in array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

My purpose is to check if value entered by user in the input field is already available in an array stored in the localstorage. If yes, print the array if not add the new value in the storage. I am getting my array back on button click but the code isn't working correctly. The output is:
["hh", "try", "vogue", "vogue", "try2", "try2", "try2", "try2"]

Above are the entered values which are getting added repetitively. I know it's a stupid issue but have least experience with handling arrays in localstorage. Any help would be appreciated. (I tried the solutions provided in similar questions on stackoverflow but no luck)

```
<html class=" reevoomark_ATY">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Special Offers</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <input id="coupon"> <button style="width:50px;padding:10px;background:grey;height:30px;border:1px solid grey" id="button">Apply</button>
    <input id="stored">
    <script>

            var coupons = ['hh'];
            var storedNames;
            localStorage.setItem("coupons", JSON.stringify(coupons));
            $('#button').on('click', function(){
                storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("coupons"));
                var enteredValue = $('#coupon').val();
                for(i=0; i <storedNames.length; i++) {
                    if(enteredValue === storedNames[i]) {
                        console.log("value Exist!!");
                        console.log(storedNames[]);
                    }
                    else {
                       console.log("in else");
                        coupons.push(enteredValue);
                        localStorage.setItem("coupons", JSON.stringify(coupons));
                        storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("coupons"));

                    }

                    }



            });



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't just check the first value and decide if the input's value is already in. You should check it with a variable out of the loop scope. If you find the value on the loop, set that variable to true and get out (break). So you'll know if it's already in or not. Another way is using the built in function Array.indexOf, so you won't need that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to push the names if it doesn't exist in the stored names. Refer attached code.

```
    <html class=" reevoomark_ATY">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Special Offers</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <input id="coupon"> <button style="width:50px;padding:10px;background:grey;height:30px;border:1px solid grey" id="button">Apply</button>
    <input id="stored">
    <script>

            var coupons = ['hh'];
            localStorage.setItem("coupons", JSON.stringify(coupons));
            $('#button').on('click', function(){
                var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("coupons"));
                var enteredValue = $('#coupon').val();
                if (storedNames.includes(enteredValue)) {
                    console.log("value Exist!!");
                  console.log(storedNames);
                } else {
                    console.log("in else");
                  storedNames.push(enteredValue);
                  localStorage.setItem("coupons", JSON.stringify(storedNames));
                }
            });



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```